# Can I show localized Drop In UI using Braintree iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, paypal, braintree

I have integrated Braintree Drop-In UI in my app and every thing is working perfectly :)
I just want to know that can I show localized UI? Is it supported in current version of iOS SDK? For example if current locale is french.. i can set it by doing some thing like `[self.braintree setLocale:@"fr"]` etc.

I have searched several Braintree forums and haven't got any answer regarding this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On an iOS integration, yes it's supported.
Currently, the Drop-in option is available in 18 languages on iOS and Android, but only in English (US) on the web.

Here's the [SDK details](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/tree/master/Braintree/Drop-In/Localization) on iOS localization bundles

Comment: I have added french locale in the app but its not showing up? Any guess? I have also checked the Braintree SDK and the localized resources are present there..

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan, pp_pduan's answer is definitely correct. Did you try setting `languageOrLocale` to `fr` as [documented in the client library](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/blob/7e35b0c6000198df082c015422149413a6206c27/Braintree/PayPal/mSDK/PayPalConfiguration.h#L82)? If not, I would really recommend [reaching out to Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/]) to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Language and locale setting is only for paypal.. not for drop-in UI

Answer (score 0):

If you're integrating via Cocoapods, then the localizations are automatically available to you when you switch the device language.

However, if you're doing a manual integration (i.e. dragging and dropping the raw Braintree SDK files into your project), you will need to create a resource bundle named `Braintree-Drop-In-Localization`, add the localized `.strings` files for the desired languages, and add that resource bundle to the app.

Comment: Can i change dropin language manually without changing device language ??